# Can not create any file in /usr/bin

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I install anything like `sudo apt install -y putty`

I get error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 imagemagick : Depends: imagemagick-6.q16 (>= 8:6.9.2.10+dfsg-2~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try `apt --fix-broken install`

I get error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libept1.6.0
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  imagemagick-6.q16 netpbm
Suggested packages:
  imagemagick-doc autotrace enscript ffmpeg gimp gnuplot grads graphviz hp2xx
  html2ps libwmf-bin mplayer povray radiance texlive-base-bin transfig
  ufraw-batch
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  imagemagick-6.q16 netpbm
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,444 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,009 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 193102 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../imagemagick-6.q16_8%3a6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking imagemagick-6.q16 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick-6.q16_8%3a6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/animate-im6.q16.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/animate-im6.q16'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../netpbm_2%3a10.0-15.3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking netpbm (2:10.0-15.3build1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/netpbm_2%3a10.0-15.3build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/pbmtobbnbg.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/pbmtobbnbg'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick-6.q16_8%3a6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/netpbm_2%3a10.0-15.3build1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I check `ls -al /usr`

I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      69632 Jul 23 15:16 bin
```

And I am not able to create any file in `/usr/bin directory`

How can I create any file in `/usr/bin directory` so that `apt --fix-broken install` can work?

Comment: "When I try `apt --fix-broken install`" Are you actually typing `sudo apt --fix-broken install`? If not, the lack of `sudo` is your problem.

Comment: still same error in it. Why does root not have write access to /usr/bin directory

Comment: Does `sudo touch /usr/bin/file` succeed?

Comment: Try `chattr -i /usr/bin` (or even, with `-R`)?

Comment: chattr -i /usr/bin worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tom-yan "chattr -i /usr/bin" worked

Comment: Great that you were able to solve the problem. But it's practice here to ask people who provide a solution in the comments to post them as an answer, so they can get the credit that is due.

Answer (score -1):

$ sudo apt-get clean

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall "Application"

$ sudo apt-get -f install

Replace application with whatever you're trying to install

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).